# C# deployment on whatever machine X86, X64 or AnyCpu

Tags: c#, deployment, x86, 64-bit, anycpu

I am a C# programmer. In my company we develop a program that, with a single executable, is deployed on various machines.
My boss says that the only way to do that is to make a X86 executable that if working on X86 machines will surely work on X64 too.
So I would like to know: is this the correct? And what are the drawbacks of having the same exe working on X86/X64.
In any case what's the AnyCpu setting for.

Additionally since most of the IT companies diversify in X86/X64 wouldn't it be better?

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: Possibly not. I am willing to know what are the drawbacks of my company's choice of using always X86.

Comment: You asked at least 3 questions, and that link answers 2 of them directly, the last (*is this the correct*) is depends on your program and what libraries it uses / assumptions it makes.

Comment: Ok I will read it all more thoroughly.

Comment: Do you need the extra memory that x64 allows you to address? If not, there's no real need to target x64 at all and x86 is fine.

Comment: @Spender Thank you for this information. Could you tell me something more about this? I have to handle one (or more) shape with 10^6 point. So a huge polylinesegment. And my goal is going for speed. As I told you I am not aware of the target computer that can be old and slow or viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build/debug options in Visual Studio you can select Any CPU in the Platform target. This makes sure your exe can run on both.
For programming: Make sure you check the operating system version in your code when accessing the registry.

Comment: Thanx. So what is better AnyCpu or split into X86 and X64?

Comment: I think Any CPU. You can allways include sections in your code to handle differences.